# Create table and immediately use it in function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

I want to create a SQL function that looks roughly like this:

```
create function foo()
returns void
set search_path = 'pg_catalog, pg_temp'
as $$
    create temporary table a (b int) on commit drop;

    insert into a select generate_series(0, 10);
$$ language sql;
```

That is, I want to create a temporary table and then immediately use it in the same function, to fill it with data and then read it back. (In actual practice, the data is calculated from a complex join operation, and is then used to generate various reports. A CTE is not practical because the data is required for multiple operations.)

However, when I execute the statement above to create the function, I encounter this error:

```
SQL error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "a" does not exist
```

That is, postgres apparently refuses to compile the function because it references a table that doesn't exist. However, that is of course entirely the intention, as the table should be created in the very same function it is referenced in.

If I create the temporary table before I create the function, I can create and run the function just fine. However, the table is very much intended to live in `pg_temp`, ensuring that multiple concurrent sessions can use the `foo` function without seeing each other's data, and also ensuring that the data gets dropped when it is no longer needed. Besides, when I create the function `foo` by connecting with a new session, creating `a`, creating `foo` and then committing (dropping `a`), then in subsequent transaction `foo` fails on call with this error:

```
SQL error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "a" does not exist
  at: SQL function "foo" during startup
```

Requiring each connecting session to create the `a` table themselves before calling `foo` works, but is obviously utterly silly (and exposes the function's implementation details to the caller).

How can I get this function to work in the way that I expect?

Comment: Changing `language sql` to `language plpgsql` and wrapping the bowels of the function in `begin ... end` "solves" this issue, but certainly that's not the real answer?

Comment: If you go the plpgsql route you will want to make all the queries that access "a" dynamic (EXECUTE ...) so that they are re-bound to tne "new version of a" each time the query is run.

Comment: Move `set search_path = 'pg_catalog, pg_temp'` to after the `create temporary table ...`.

Comment: FYI, a temporary table is always going to live in `pg_temp` more specifically `pg_temp_nn` where *nn* is a number and `pg_temp` is an alias for a session's `pg_temp_nn`. Also `pg_temp` by default will be first in line in the search path. See *search_path* here [Statement Behavior](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-STATEMENT). In other words you don't need to specify it.

Comment: Right, thank you. I only added `set search_path` while investigating this problem, as I wanted to make sure this wasn't a weird namespacing/schema issue. (Moving the `set search_path` inside the body of the function doesn't fix the issue either.)